# Can't run my code though a loop however manually copying and pasting works

Tags: c++, string, recursion, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

This bit of code works. I can also copy paste from start to end several times inside my main and it will still work.

```
int main()
{
string str;

cout << "Input a palindrome: "; // Start
getline(cin, str);

if (testPalindrome(str) == 1)
    cout << "Your input is a palindrome: True" << endl;
else
    cout << "Your input is a palindrome: False" << endl;

cout << endl; // End


cout << "\nCreated by,\nNorman Ettedgui" << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

However this bit of code will not work and the error I get is a strings out of bound within my function (oddly enough before the function call).

This is my testPalindrome function:

```
bool testPalindrome(string str)
{
string newStr;

for (int i = 1; i < str.length() - 1; i++)
    newStr += str[i];

if (newStr.length() > 1)
    testPalindrome(newStr);

if (str[0] == str[str.length() - 1])
    return true;
}
```

This is what I'm trying to run:

```
int main()
{
string str;

int i = 0;

while (i != -1)
{
    cout << "Input a palindrome: ";
    getline(cin, str);

    if (testPalindrome(str) == 1)
        cout << "Your input is a palindrome: True" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Your input is a palindrome: False" << endl;

    cout << "-1 to Exit or any other number to continue: ";
    cin >> i;

    cout << endl;
}

cout << "\nCreated by,\nNorman Ettedgui" << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I feel like I should point out that your name is on display. In case you don't want it to be and simply forgot about it. And regarding your issue: print some debug statements right before the error to find out what has an unexpected value.

Comment: You check the length of `newStr` but still try to access it's elements even if it's empty.

Comment: `bool testPalindrome(string str)` should be `bool testPalindrome(string & str)`?

Comment: Your code doesn't have many issues. It's how you read input that's the problem. The second loop will get a segfault. Also, @CaptainObvlious I'm not sure that's true. And, sebas, that's not exactly necessary? :p

Comment: will the test palindrome ever return false ?

Comment: @Roma-MT I think the recursive call needs to "return testPalindrome(newStr);" and also when str[0]!=str[str.length()-1] to return false.

Comment: @anonymous yes ,I tried to point it )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following function

```
bool testPalindrome( string s)
{
   return ( s.size() < 2 ? true 
                         : s.front() == s.back() && testPalindrome( s.substr( 1, s.size() -2 ) ) );
}
```

Also in main substitute this statement

```
if (testPalindrome(str) == 1)
```

for

```
if ( testPalindrome(str) )
```

If you use getline and operator >> simultaneously then you should use ignore to skip ENTER key
(DO not forget include `<limits>`)

```
#include <limits>
while (i != -1)
{
    cout << "Input a palindrome: ";

    cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max() );
    getline(cin, str);

    //...
    cin >> i;

    cout << endl;
}
```

**I will explain you why you got the error**. Without statement with the call of ignore function getline read an empty string. So str was empty. In function testPalindrome there is statement

```
for (int i = 1; i < str.length() - 1; i++)
```

As for an empty string its length is equal to 0 then expression

```
str.length() - 1
```

has the maximum value for the unsigned type because the type of this expression is some unsigned integral type and the internal representation of -1 corresponds to the maximim unsigned value.
So variable i will be always less than -1 and you get memory access violation.

Also I would use another loop without using additional variable i.

```
while ( true )
{
       cout << "Input a palindrome: ";

       string str;
       getline(cin, str);

       if ( str.empty() ) break;

       //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood what was going on. Also I liked the last loop I'll use that to keep my code simple, I don't want to include anything fancy since its for a beginners class homework. And if I may say so, your recursive palindrome function was sublime.

Answer (score 0):

`if (newStr.length()>1)` only handles the condition when newStr.length() is >1. You need an else statement to handle when the condition: `if (newStr.length()>1)`  is false.

Comment: And also , on a recursive call you should return aren't you ?
I mean when calling recursively `testPalindrome` should be inside return.